# Is it by design that I am seeing so much empty space instead of the content of the question?

Tags: bug, design, homepage

I saw the change just now and I feel something is weird. I think it is the empty space between the questions that I think it should be the content of each question, which is missing (or not). I am not sure if this is by design. Any clarification?

**New**
[image: new]

**Old**
[image: old]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-else-eventually

Comment: There is something unusual with titles of the questions you have - normally it is "I have a problem", "Why this code does not work" and "Please help me" :) ... Looks like I need some other tags to "watch"...

Comment: When I first looked at new design, I also though that something is missing. But guess what, it does not. In "Top Questions" section, questions didn't have descriptions in old design either. but old design looks much better in my opinion. New design has a lot empty space, and question statistic is too small. It's hard to quickly see all relevant things about the question.

Comment: The "Watched" box is the thing taking up the lion's share of the room. While the new records are bigger (unless the title wraps to two lines, in which case they're about the same), they get *much* bigger with that wretched "Watched" box.

Comment: Empty space is (was?) part of the so-called [Web 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0) (Jeff Atwood said or wrote something to that effect at the time). I suppose in contrast to cluttered web pages.